# node mongoose updating an Object in Array doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update an Array of objects wo any success..
the update statement does not work ..

I may have to update the table instance array and update it with the new valueand then save the table...

```
  const picked = table.meta.permissions.find(obj => obj._id == req.params.permissionId);
  console.log('picked: %j', picked); // need to update it !
```

// how can I update this permission object with the new value from req.body ?

```
  table.save()
    .then(savedTable => res.json(savedTable))
    .catch(e => next(e););
```

I have an Array of permissions in a 'meta' field:
**MODEL**

```
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const Permission = new Schema({
      permission: {
        role_id: { type: String },
        canWrite: { type: Boolean }
      }
    });
    const TableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      meta: {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        permissions: [Permission],
        ...
      },
      ...
    );
```

In the controller , I firstly load the requested table and append it to the req object, then I execute the updatePermission function, and try to update the table instance permission with new values using $set

**CONTROLLER**

```
    import Table from '../../models/table.model';

    /**
     * Load table  and append to req.
     */
    function load(req, res, next, id) {
      Table.get(id)
        .then((table) => {
          req.table = table;
          return next();
        })
        .catch(e => next(e));
    }

    function updatePermission(req, res, next) {
      const table = req.table;

      console.log('Current table.meta.permissions: %j', table.meta.permissions, '\n');
      console.log('update permission: ', req.params.permissionId, ' with: ', req.body, '\n');

      const query = { 'meta.permissions._id': req.params.permissionId }
      const update = { $set: { 'meta.permissions.$.permission': req.body } };
      const options = { new: true};
      table.update(query, update, options)
        .then(savedTable => res.json(savedTable))
        .catch((e) => { next(e); });
```

}

The console log displays the current  table permissions and the req.params and req.body

Why the update statement doesn't run correctly

thanks for feedback

Comment: You should find out what exactly is causing that 500 error (by checking logfiles and/or explicitly logging errors).

Comment: this is one of my problem in test phase ... how can I get Mongoose output log somewhere ...
In my index.js file I added :

  mongoose.set('debug', (collectionName, method, query, doc) => {
    debug(`${collectionName}.${method}`, util.inspect(query, false, 20), doc);
  });

but I don't own where the out is printed ...

Comment: You should add [proper error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) to Express. I'm not sure what `debug` is in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting me on the right track... in my error handler , I forgot to changed the environment to 'test ... 

I am now getting the stack trace ... see my UPDATE in the question window

Comment: That stack trace looks like a red herring: it's breaking inside of Mocha for some weird reason, but that's not the cause of the 500 error.

Comment: yes, the issue actually comes from the table.update() which doesn't work ...  as I append the table to be updated to the req object, I should modify it directly then save it with table.save()  I updated the question
thanks for your feedbacks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this issue but I don't know if it's the best one ?
I update the table object using some() then I save the table..

```
    function updatePermission(req, res, next) {
      const table = req.table;

      table.meta.permissions.some((obj, idx) => {
        if (obj._id == req.params.permissionId) {
          table.meta.permissions[idx].permission = req.body; 
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });

      table.save()
        .then(savedTable => res.json(savedTable))
        .catch(e => next(e); );
    }
```